# Changing the view - Tetris Game - MVC

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, tetris

I'm trying to make Tetris in JAVA with MVC. Now, I wrote everything and it all works fine. I only have one problem left; changing the views. When I get a score of 200, for example, the view has to change. I want to change the squares to circles in my gameboard. But I cannot make it work. I could do it with some methods, but I want to manage it with different classes. I have an abstractView class, the real views extend this abstract class. How do I switch from 1 to 2? Does this happen in the controller? Or do I have to write some code in the model aswell to make the change?

**AbstractView**

```
package Tetris;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public abstract class abstractView extends JFrame implements BoardObserver
{
    ControllerInterface controller;
    ModelInterface model;
    JButton goDown;
    JButton goLeft;
    JButton goRight;
    JButton turn;
    JButton pause;
    JButton restart;
    JLabel scoreLabel;
    JLabel scoreText;
    JLabel levelLabel;
    JLabel levelText;
    JLabel pauseLabel;
    Timer timer;      

public abstractView(final ControllerInterface controller, ModelInterface model)
{
    this.model=model;
    this.controller=controller;    
    createView();
    this.model.registerObserver(this);
}

public void createView()
{   
    this.setTitle("Tetris Jasper Nuytten");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
    this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400,500)); 
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,500));    
    this.setResizable(false);
    setLayout(null);

    goRight=new JButton("»");
    goRight.setBounds(330, 370, 45, 20);

    goLeft=new JButton("«");
    goLeft.setBounds(235, 370, 45, 20);

    turn = new JButton("Turn");
    turn.setBounds(270,330,70,30);
    this.turn.setVisible(true);

    goDown= new JButton("Down");
    goDown.setBounds(270,400,70,30);

    pause=new JButton("|>");       
    pause.setBounds(230,240,50,40);

    restart=new JButton("Restart");
    restart.setBounds(300,240,80,40);
    restart.setEnabled(false);

    scoreLabel = new JLabel();
    scoreLabel.setText("SCORE :");  
    scoreLabel.setBounds(230,90,70,40);

    scoreText = new JLabel();
    scoreText.setText(Integer.toString(this.controller.getScore()));  
    scoreText.setBounds(290,90,70,40);

    levelLabel = new JLabel();
    levelLabel.setText("LEVEL  :");  
    levelLabel.setBounds(230,120,70,40);

    levelText = new JLabel();
    levelText.setText(Integer.toString(this.controller.getLevel()));  
    levelText.setBounds(290,120,70,40);    

    pauseLabel = new JLabel();
    pauseLabel.setText("PAUSE");
    pauseLabel.setBounds(260,180,70,40);
    pauseLabel.setFont(new Font(pauseLabel.getFont().getName(),Font.PLAIN,20));
    //this.scoreText.setSize();     

    this.add(goLeft);
    this.add(goRight);
    this.add(goDown);
    this.add(turn);
    this.add(restart);

    this.add(pause);
    this.add(scoreText);
    this.add(scoreLabel);
    this.add(levelText);
    this.add(levelLabel);
    this.add(pauseLabel);
    // The actions for when a button has been pressed.
    goDown.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() 
    {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
            {
                goDownButtonClicked(evt);
            }
    }
    );
    goLeft.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() 
    {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
            {
                goLeftButtonClicked(evt);
            }
    }
    );
    goRight.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() 
    {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
            {
                goRightButtonClicked(evt);
            }
    }
    );   
    pause.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() 
    {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
            {
                pauseButtonClicked(evt);
            }
    }
    );
    restart.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() 
    {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
            {
                restartButtonClicked(evt);
            }
    }
    );
    turn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() 
    {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
            {
                turnButtonClicked(evt);
            }
    }
    );
    // Activate Keys on keyboard.
    this.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() 
    {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) 
            {
                KeyReleased(evt);
            }
        });   
    this.setFocusable(true);    //To make the keys active
    this.setVisible(true);
}
private void goDownButtonClicked(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                         
    this.controller.goDown();       
}                                              
private void pauseButtonClicked(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{
    this.controller.pause();
    this.requestFocus();
    repaintz(this.getGraphics());
}
private void turnButtonClicked(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                         
    this.controller.turn();        
}                                
private void goLeftButtonClicked(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                         
    this.controller.goLeft();
} 
private void goRightButtonClicked(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                         
    this.controller.goRight();
} 
private void restartButtonClicked(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{
    if(this.controller.getGameState())
    this.controller.restart();
}
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g)
{   
    super.paint(g);
    for (int i=0;i<this.controller.getBoard().length;i++)
    { 
     for(int j = 0; j<this.controller.getBoard()[0].length;j++)
     {
        switch(this.controller.getBoard()[i][j]) 
        {
            case 1: 
            {
                g.setColor(Color.PINK);
            };
            break;
            case 2: 
            {                        
                g.setColor(Color.cyan);                     
            };
            break;
            case 3: 
            {                       
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);                       
            };
            break;
            case 4: 
            {                                           
                g.setColor(Color.RED);                       
            };
            break;
            case 5: 
            {                        
                g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);                       
            };
            break;
            case 6: 
            {                        
                g.setColor(Color.orange);                       
            };
            break;
            case 7: 
            {                                                
                g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            };
            break;
            case 0: 
            {
                g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);                            
            };
            break;                        
        }
        g.drawRect((j*20)+20,i*20+40,20,20);    
        g.fillRect((j*20)+20,i*20+40,20,20);
     }                
    }         
    // Show the next tetris shape.
    for (int rowMini=0;rowMini<4;rowMini++)
    {
     for (int columnMini=0;columnMini<3;columnMini++)
     {
         if(this.controller.getFuturePiece()[rowMini][columnMini]>0)
         {
             g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
         }
         else
         {
            g.setColor(Color.white);
         }
         g.drawRect((columnMini*20)+232,rowMini*20+40,20,20);    
         g.fillRect((columnMini*20)+232,rowMini*20+40,20,20);
     }
    }
}
// Methoden voor verschillende views
public abstract void repaintz(Graphics g);
//public abstract void repainty(Graphics g);
//public abstract void repaintx(Graphics g);
public void drawFutureShape(Graphics g)
{
    for (int rowMini=0;rowMini<4;rowMini++)
         {
             for (int columnMini=0;columnMini<3;columnMini++)
             {
                 if(this.controller.getFuturePiece()[rowMini][columnMini]>0)
                 {
                     g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                 }
                 else
                {
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                }
                 g.drawRect((columnMini*20)+232,rowMini*20+40,20,20);    
                 g.fillRect((columnMini*20)+232,rowMini*20+40,20,20);                 
             }
         }
}
public void calculateLogics()
{
    if(!this.controller.getGameState())
    { 
    this.restart.setEnabled(false);        
    scoreText.setText(Integer.toString(this.controller.getScore()));        
    levelText.setText(Integer.toString(this.controller.getLevel()));       
    }  
    else
    {
        this.restart.setEnabled(true);
        this.scoreText.setText("GAME OVER");           
    }
    if(this.controller.getPauseState())
    {
        this.pause.setText("||");
        this.pauseLabel.setEnabled(false);         
    }
    else
    {
        this.pause.setText("|>");
        this.pauseLabel.setEnabled(true);         
    }
}    
@Override
public void updateBoard()
{  
  repaintz(this.getGraphics());
  this.requestFocus();  
}
// Code to link a key with a method.
public void KeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent e)
{    
    if(e.getKeyChar()=='p')
    {
        this.controller.pause();            
    }    
    switch(e.getKeyCode())
    {
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP     :this.controller.turn();break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN   :this.controller.goDown();break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT   :this.controller.goLeft();break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT  :this.controller.goRight();break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE  :this.controller.dropDown();break;
    }
}
```

}

**VIEW1**

```
    package Tetris;

import java.awt.*;
public class TetrisView extends abstractView

{   
public TetrisView(ControllerInterface controller, ModelInterface model) {
    super(controller, model);
}

@Override
public void repaintz(Graphics g)
{    
    calculateLogics();      
       for (int i=0;i<this.controller.getBoard().length;i++)
         { 
             for(int j = 0; j<this.controller.getBoard()[0].length;j++)
             {
                switch(this.controller.getBoard()[i][j]) 
                {
                    case 1: 
                    {
                        g.setColor(Color.PINK);
                        g.fillRect((j*20)+20,i*20+40,20,20);
                        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                        g.drawRect((j*20)+20,i*20+40,20,20);
                    };
                    break;
                    case 2: 
                    {                        
                        g.setColor(Color.cyan); 
                        g.fillRect((j*20)+20,i*20+40,20,20);
                        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                        g.drawRect((j*20)+20,i*20+40,20,20);
                    };
                    break;
                    case 3: 
                    {                       
                        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);                       
                        g.fillRect((j*20)+20,i*20+40,20,20);
                        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                        g.drawRect((j*20)+20,i*20+40,20,20);
                    };
                    break;
                    case 4: 
                    {                                           
                        g.setColor(Color.RED);              
                        g.fillRect((j*20)+20,i*20+40,20,20);
                        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                        g.drawRect((j*20)+20,i*20+40,20,20);
                    };
                    break;
                    case 5: 
                    {                        
                        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);           
                        g.fillRect((j*20)+20,i*20+40,20,20);
                        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                        g.drawRect((j*20)+20,i*20+40,20,20);
                    };
                    break;
                    case 6: 
                    {                        
                        g.setColor(Color.orange);           
                        g.fillRect((j*20)+20,i*20+40,20,20);
                        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                        g.drawRect((j*20)+20,i*20+40,20,20);
                    };
                    break;
                    case 7: 
                    {                                                
                        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                        g.fillRect((j*20)+20,i*20+40,20,20);
                        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                        g.drawRect((j*20)+20,i*20+40,20,20);
                    };
                    break;
                    case 0: 
                    {                           
                        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);       
                        g.fillRect((j*20)+20,i*20+40,20,20);                        
                    };
                    break;                        
                }

             }
         }
   drawFutureShape(this.getGraphics());
}          
}
```

**VIEW2**

```
package Tetris;

import java.awt.*;
public class TetrisView2 extends abstractView
{  



public TetrisView2(ControllerInterface controller, ModelInterface model) {
    super(controller, model);
}


@Override
public void repaintz(Graphics g)
{    
    calculateLogics();         
    for (int i=0;i<this.controller.getBoard().length;i++)
         { 
             for(int j = 0; j<this.controller.getBoard()[0].length;j++)
             {
                switch(this.controller.getBoard()[i][j]) 
                {
                    case 1: 
                    {
                        g.setColor(Color.PINK);
                    };
                    break;
                    case 2: 
                    {                        
                        g.setColor(Color.cyan);                     
                    };
                    break;
                    case 3: 
                    {                       
                        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);                       
                    };
                    break;
                    case 4: 
                    {                                           
                        g.setColor(Color.RED);                       
                    };
                    break;
                    case 5: 
                    {                        
                        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);                       
                    };
                    break;
                    case 6: 
                    {                        
                        g.setColor(Color.orange);                       
                    };
                    break;
                    case 7: 
                    {                                                
                        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    };
                    break;
                    case 0: 
                    {                           
                        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);           
                        g.drawRect((j*20)+20,i*20+40,20,20);                        
                        g.fillRect((j*20)+20,i*20+40,20,20);
                    };
                    break;                        
                }
                 g.drawRoundRect((j*20)+20,i*20+40,20,20,20,20);
                 g.fillRoundRect((j*20)+20,i*20+40,20,20,20,20);                   
             }
         }
   drawFutureShape(this.getGraphics());
}    
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity why are you using MVC for a tetris game?

Comment: School assignment, learning to work with MVC. I thought this was a legit way of working? Even for Tetris?

Comment: I would say not.  It is an MVC.  The M stands for model, or data, which is really the most important element.  I would say the view is the least of all important.  I have used MVC architecture for software that has zero views.  (Server applications before MVC was cool.)

Tetris, as with most games, has data that is trivial.

Comment: See also this simpler MVC [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513).

Comment: @Pete Belford, I'm not sure that I understand completely what you are trying to say?

Comment: Try using Java applet.